# use jquery datetimepicker in navGrid jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I add jquery datetimepicker and label to navGrid of jqgrid?
I want the ability to search by date in navGrid of jqgrid beside paging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
myGrid.navButtonAdd("#pagerId",{caption:"Search<input type='text' id='datePicker'>", buttonicon:"ui-icon-search", onClickButton:customSearch, position: "last", title:"", cursor: "pointer"});

function customSearch() {
    //Custom Search Logic
}
```

add this on load complete of the grid:

```
loadComplete: function (data) {
    $('#datePicker').datepicker();
},
```

Comment: Thanks. This is expected solution :)

Comment: how to change position?(for example before paging-info)