# Problems using bootstraps datetimepicker in jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap-4, jqgrid

I'm using **jqgrid** to display different data entries in my frontend. In one column I display a timestamp and would like to enable the user to edit date and time using a datetimepicker. I **started with a datepicker and everything worked**.

Now I'm using a datetimepicker *sometimes* when I open the edit-dialog the field that is supposed to display date and time is blank. For example the timestamp "30.11.2022 00:00" is not displayed in the edit-dialog and the timestamp "05.11.2022 00:00" is displayed. When I use a simple datepicker everything works fine. In the grid overview all data entries' timestamps are displayed correctly.
Furthermore **the datetimepicker doesn't open**, neither for the data entries where the field for timestamp is blank, nor for the data entries where the timestamp is displayed correctly.
There are no logs in the console so I don't really know where to start looking for a solution.

Here is my code:

```
    {
        label: "Valid Until",
        name: 'validUntil',
        width: intColumnWidth,
        headerTitle: "Valid Until",
        editrules: {
            required: true
        },
        editable: true,
        formatter: 'date',
        editoptions: {
            dataInit: function (element) {
                jQuery(element).datetimepicker({
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

From the backend I receive the timestamp as a string and in the format dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm. Therefore I tried adding the formatoptions property and also the dateformat property like so:

```
    {
        label: "Valid from",
        name: 'validUntil',
        width: intColumnWidth,
        headerTitle: "Valid from",
        editrules: {
            required: true
        },
        editable: true,
        formatter: 'date',
        formatoptions: {
            srcformat: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            newformat: 'd.m.Y H:i'
        },
        editoptions: {
            dataInit: function (element) {
                jQuery(element).datetimepicker({
                    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                    timeFormat: "HH:mm"
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

I read that a common mistake ist that not all necessary libraries are imported or that they are imported in the wrong order. I imported the following libraries in the following order:

- jquery-ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.css
- free-jqgrid/4.15.5/css/ui.jqgrid.css
- bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css
- ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.7.14/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css
- jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js
- jquery-ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js
- ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js
- bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js
- ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js
- ajax/libs/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/5.0.1/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js
- free-jqgrid/4.15.5/js/i18n/grid.locale-de.js
- ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"

**Other things I tried:**

- I verified that I receive the timestamp string as expected from the backend.
- I changed dataIntit to *loadComplete* like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146907/use-jquery-datetimepicker-in-navgrid-jqgrid) suggests. When I do that all timestamps are displayed correctly but the datetimepicker still doesn't open
- I changed dataIntit to *onInitializeForm* like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24088792/datetimepicker-not-working-inside-jqgrid-but-its-working-outside-of-it) suggests. When I do that all timestamps are displayed correctly but the datetimepicker still doesn't open

Does anyone know a solution??

Comment: I'm not sure that this version of the datetimepicker will work with jQuery 3.51. It is simple to check - prepare example only with jQuery 3.51 and this version of the timepicker and try to run.

Comment: Updating to the latest version of jQuery doesn't solve the problem. Where can I find the version of the datetimepicker associated with jQuery 3.5.1?

Comment: you can check authors web site - usually this is put in the header of the files. [Try here](https://getdatepicker.com/), but you will need to know that the last version of the script is Vanilla JavaScript -  not jQuery depended - see demos.